# Replace A-Z and 0-9 in query sql postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, replace

I currently have strings eg `E-1082067D` and I'd like to query out a simplified version of these for each row. Returning L (for Letter in place of A-Z), S(for a symbol) and N (for a Number 0-9). I cannot update the database or create a new table as I do not have privileges and simply want to query the data.

So far I've split my string into individual characters and now want to Replace the split characters and concatenate these back together to give my end result eg in place of `E-1082067D` would be `LSDDDDDDDL`.

Any feedback on how below could be cleaned up or if I'm going about this in the wrong way would be appreciated.

s

```
elect site_name,natid, x, COUNT (x), substring(natid,1,1)as a,
substring(natid,2,1)as b,
substring(natid,3,1)as c,
substring(natid,4,1)as d,
substring(natid,5,1)as e,
substring(natid,6,1)as f,
substring(natid,7,1)as g,
substring(natid,8,1)as h,
substring(natid,9,1)as i,
substring(natid,10,1)as j,
substring(natid,11,1)as k,
substring(natid,12,1)as l,
substring(natid,13,1)as m 
from (
select site_name, subject_id, natid,natidchk, length(natid)as x
from demog 
order by x) as y
group by natid, site_name,  x
order by site_name, x;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved with using multiple regular expressions:

```
with data (natid) as (
   values 
      ('E-1082067D'), 
      ('X&42FOO567$BAR')
)
select natid, 
       regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(natid, '([A-Z])', 'L', 'ig'), '[0-9]', 'N', 'ig'), '[-&$]', 'S', 'ig')
from data;
```

First all occurrences of `A-Z` are replaced with `L`, then all occurrences of `0-9` are replace with `N` and `-`, `&` or `$` are replaced with `S`

The above returns:

```
natid          | regexp_replace
---------------+---------------
E-1082067D     | LSNNNNNNNL    
X&42FOO567$BAR | LSNNLLLNNNSLLL
```

Comment: Amazing! This worked so much better than substring to separate then replace then concatenate! Off to look into regular expressions more!